# For...in loop results in use of undeclared indetifier

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm still new to Objective-C (coming from a Java and C# background), and I'm implementing a plugin system for an iOS SDK I'm developing.

I've defined my plugin header (Plugin.h) as follows (the java counterpath would be an abstract class, correct me if I'm doing anything wrong here).

```
@protocol Plugin <NSObject>
@required
- (void)initialize;
- (NSString *) getPluginName;
- (NSString *) getVersion;
@end
```

I then have a method in my SDK that can be used to register plugins. The array will be an array of objects that inherit from TFTPlugin.

```
+ (void)registerPlugins:(NSMutableArray*) array
{   
    for(Plugin *plugin in array)
    {
        [pluginClasses addObject:plugin];
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error at the for loop: Use of undeclared identifier 'plugin'.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, corrected the code. Still the same error though.

Comment: You need to copy and paste the REAL code instead of having to fix typo after typo.

Comment: `Plugin` is not a class, correct? It's a protocol. So the compiler will give an error when you declare an object of type `Plugin`.

Comment: Yeah Plugin is not a class, but a protocol classes can implement.
I'm porting this over from an android SDK where the Plugin class is abstract. Is this not the right approach?

Comment: Essentially, protocols are a way of guaranteeing that certain methods should be implemented by a class. It doesn't tell you anything else about the structure of the class, which could be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(id plugin in array){
    if([[plugin class] conformsToProtocol:@protocol(Plugin)]) {
        [pluginClasses addObject:plugin];
    }
}
```

The checking to see if it conforms to the protocol is optional if you know that everything you are passing in actually does.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: A slightly better solution (but without any effect here) would be `for(id<Plugin> plugin in array)`.

Comment: Good point, although note that you still need the `conformsToProtocol` if you want to avoid runtime errors from unexpected non plugins in the array.